# Control a div with two checkboxes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am learning AngularJs, any help is much appreciated, trying to display the div content that is checked, if nothing checked the div with 'selected' class name should appear.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" ng-model="aCheck" ng-change="checkbox1Func()">A
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" ng-model="bCheck" ng-change="checkbox2Func()">B

<div ng-if="selected">Hello from div container</div>

<div ng-if="aCheck">Hello from checkbox1</div>
<div ng-if="bCheck">Hello from checkbox2</div>
</body>

</html>
```

> And the script

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.selected=true;

$scope.checkbox1Func=function(a){
$scope.selected=false;
};
$scope.checkbox2Func=function(b){
$scope.selected=false;
};

if($scope.aCheck === false && $scope.bCheck===false){
$scope.selected=true;
} 

//   $('.myCheckbox').click(function() {
//     $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
// });

});
```

Comment: plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/xz1RCPnjMMXg2aoRa00N?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your existing logic will work if you check the if condition

```
if($scope.aCheck === false && $scope.bCheck===false){
    $scope.selected=true;
}
```

inside both the functions `checkbox1Func` and `checkbox2Func`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the check inside a function and call it on the ng-change event,

```
 $scope.valid = function() {
    if ($scope.aCheck === false && $scope.bCheck === false) {
      $scope.selected = true;
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" ng-model="aCheck" ng-change="checkbox1Func();valid();">A
 <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" ng-model="bCheck" ng-change="checkbox2Func();valid();">B
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.selected = true;

  $scope.checkbox1Func = function(a) {
    $scope.selected = false;
  };
  $scope.checkbox2Func = function(b) {
    $scope.selected = false;
  };
  $scope.valid = function() {
    if ($scope.aCheck === false && $scope.bCheck === false)   {
      $scope.selected = true;
    }
  }
 

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" ng-model="aCheck" ng-change="checkbox1Func();valid();">A
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" ng-model="bCheck" ng-change="checkbox2Func();valid();">B
    <div ng-if="selected">Hello from div container</div>
    <div ng-if="aCheck">Hello from checkbox1</div>
    <div ng-if="bCheck">Hello from checkbox2</div>
  </body>

</html>
```